# Format text normally inside of li (list item)

Tags: html, css, html-lists

In a page of my website I have a `<ul>` setup. Within each `<li>` in the `<ul>`, there is an image and some text. When I place the image in first, then try to put in the text, the text gets pushed down and can't be formatted properly. I tried to add a `vertical-align: text-top` to the image, but this just pushed the text to the top, and did not allow to move down as more text was added.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kh4xC/

HTML

```
<div id="older-videos">    
<ul>
            <li>
            <img src="../Images/Article Images/GuliyevFace14.png" class="li-image" />
            Heydər Oğuzun Rəsul Quliyevlə Müsahibəsi - 29 İyul 2012, 2-ci hissə

            </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#older-videos ul li {
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    height:162px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;

}
#older-videos ul li img{ vertical-align:text-top;
}
.li-image {
    width:250px;
    height:162px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 5px 1px 5px #888;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add and fill in the `alt` attribute on `img`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good you are declaring each `<li>` as a block element. I think the next step is to just assign a float to your image. If you want the image left of the the text just declare float: left for the `.li-image` class. I am less sure about the ability to align the text withing the `<li>` property, but you can also try vertical-align and text-align, declared for the `<li>`.

I would suggest keeping the display:block and floating the image in either case, however. That should your larger layout intent in browsers with CSS difficult.

Comment: All `<li>` elements are block by default. That line does nothing unless there are other conflicting assignments we don't know of. Other than that, `float: left` really seems to be all that's needed.

Comment: Awesome, the float:left worked on the li-image. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just place the describing text in its own `<li></li>` tag? Seems like an easy solution to your problem.

Comment: That would have a different meaning. The image and the description are _one_ entity. Each in their own `li`, they would lose that connection.